# Uninstall MySQL workbench 6.2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have MySQL workbench 6.2 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04. I installed it using the downloaded package from mysql website. A Few days ago, it stopped showing me 'Server' menu options (from the top menu), also I am unable to see the import /export related options. So I am unable to import or export databases.

How to fix this or uninstall this software? I tried installing the default MySQL workbench 6.0 from the software center, but, after installing it does not show, only the 6.2 version is available for use.

I also tried this [link](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/mysql-workbench?action=remove) but nothing worked

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench
```

results in

```
Package 'mysql-workbench' is not installed, so not removed
```

and

```
 sudo apt-get purge mysql-workbench
```

results in

```
Removing mysql-workbench (6.0.8+dfsg-2) ...
Purging configuration files for mysql-workbench (6.0.8+dfsg-2) ...
```

Looking for version 6.0 not the 6.2 version I have in use.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So i had the same package not installed error and that was because i was targeting the wrong package.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-linux-uninstalling.html

as found in this link i tried `sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench-community` and this worked for me.